# LookAt different object smoothly in unity3d

Tags: unity, c#

[image]
As picture depicted my camera moving on path i want to lookAt bath different object smoothly. Currently have tried

```
trasnform.LooAt(activePath.gameObject.transform);
```

but it producing jerky result. object suddenly lookAt to next object how to avoid it. I searched and found this sloution but it also not working

```
var targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(activePath.gameObject.transform.position - transform.position);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: Slerp is an interpolation. Delta time must be a ratio of TimeSinceLookingAtLastTarget/TotalTimeDesiredToLookAtNextTarget.  If you expect it to take 2 seconds to turn from target A to target B, and it's been .25 seconds, the interpolation ratio should be 0.125.

Answer (score 2):

Slerp is an interpolation. The final parameter T must be a ratio of TimeSinceLookingAtLastTarget/TotalTimeDesiredToLookAtNextTarget.

0 <= T <= 1

If you expect it to take 2 seconds to turn from target A to target B, and it's been .25 seconds, the interpolation ratio should be 0.125.

Time.DeltaTime is just the number of seconds in took to process the last frame.  It should always be consistently low and won't change much.  At 60FPS, that code would leave you looking 1/60th of the way between two targets.

So you will need to know the actual time and how long it should take.  When you start the turn, capture

`float SecondsToTurn = 2;  //adjust this`

`float TurnStartTime = Time.Time;`

Each frame calculate your slerpT as

`float slerpT = (Time.Time - TurnStartTime) / SecondsToTurn`

Use slerpT instead of Time.deltaTime in your Quaternion.Slerp